# Kendo Grouped Listview Tap Event

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a mobile kendo listview that is grouped.  I am trying to capture which list item i tap but when the listview is grouped the currentTarget is the "km-group-container", not the list item.  When the listview is NOT grouped, things work correctly.  Because the tapped item is the container there is no "data-uid" attribute.  Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm using this to configure the events for touch events:

```
.kendoTouch({
            filter: ">li",
            enableSwipe: true,
            touchstart: touchstart,
            tap: navigate,
            swipe: swipe
        });

function navigate(e) {
        var curUID = e.touch.currentTarget.className;
        alert(curUID);
        var itemUID = $(e.touch.currentTarget).data("uid");
        kendo.mobile.application.navigate("#edit-detailview?uid=" + itemUID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your second line of code to reflect the grouped list to:

```
filter: ">li>ul li"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .click event on your

```
.kendoMobileListView({ ...,click: function(e) {viewDetails(e)} })


function viewDetails(e){
  var model = e.dataItem; //ds.getByUid(e.view.params.uid);
  kendo.bind($("#edit-detailview"), model, kendo.mobile.ui);
  kendo.mobile.application.navigate("#edit-detailview");
}
```

I faced the same issue I opened a ticket with kendo, they recommended to use the click and it works for me. I hope it will solve your problem